# mysql calculation data in two table

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate commisions according to product commision type and its commision ratio for each sales (cash). One product has more one commision type. For example, Seller Commision, Manager Commision, Branch Commision etc.

I want to give a report sales and their commision in list.

**Product - Sale Price(Cash) - Seller Commision - Manager Commision  - Branch Commision**

**Computer    /    1000          /  1000 * 0.3    / 1000 * 0.2  /  1000 * 0.4**

I have two tables; first one is sale_table which has columns;

**sale_id, shop_id, product_id, cash**
ex: **(3,5,11,100)**

second one is product_commision_table which has columns;

**product_commision_id, shop_id, product_id, commision_type_id, commision **

**(1819, 5, 11, 9, 32),
(1820, 5, 11, 2, 0.3),
(1821, 5, 11, 7, 1),
(1822, 5, 11, 5, 0.5),
(1823, 5, 11, 6, 0.7)**

I want to calculate commisions according to cash and result should seem like:

100*32 , 100*0.3, 100*1, 100*0.5, 100*0,7

How can I do, what should be query in mysql ?

Comment: `SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE whatever = somethingelse`

Comment: 'SELECT ss.shop_reservation_id, ss.shop_id, ss.shop_product_id, spc.commision, spc.commision_type_id FROM turerp_db.shop_sale ss 
left join shop_product_commision spc 
ON ( ss.shop_id = spc.shop_id AND ss.shop_product_id = spc.shop_product_id )
order by ss.shop_id,ss.shop_product_id ;'

Comment: Also, if the column in your sales table is actually named `cash(price)` you should really rename it to either `cash` or `price`

Comment: Its name is **cash**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*, c.*, s.cash * c.commission as commission_total FROM sales_table as s, product_commissions_table as c WHERE s.product_id = c.product_id
```

Shortcut version of INNER JOIN posted by another user.